# Struts2 and Dojo (double?) publish

Tags: struts2, dojo, publishing, publish-subscribe

I am publishing with dojo topics:

```
dojo.event.topic.publish("publishThisTarget");
```

And in JSP I have listenTopics:

```
<s:url var="url2publish" action="MyAction" namespace="/public" />
    <sx:div showLoadingText="false" indicator="ajaxIndicator"
        id="content" href="%{url2publish}" theme="ajax"
        listenTopics="publishThisTarget" preload="false"
                    afterNotifyTopics="/ajaxAfter">
</sx:div>
```

The problem is, that my action is published twice and I have no clue why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with struts you have to disconnect the trigger after it was fired, and it will be reconfigured by the div content refresh.

Javascript :

```
dojo.event.topic.subscribe("/clearMsg", function(date, type, request) {
    dojo.event.topic.destroy('publishThisTarget');
});
```

JSP :

```
<s:url var="url2publish" action="MyAction" namespace="/public" />
    <sx:div showLoadingText="false" indicator="ajaxIndicator"
            id="content" href="%{url2publish}" theme="ajax"
            listenTopics="publishThisTarget" preload="false"
            beforeNotify="/clearMsg" afterNotifyTopics="/ajaxAfter">
</sx:div>
```